# Compare the 2nd highest date with the latest

Tags: mysql

Morning all, 
Looking for a bit of help with MySQL query.

Im looking for 2 things, firstly out the data below how do i compare the latest date to the 2nd latest date as i cant use MIN MAX, ASC OR DESC to get the 2nd highest. So its a Sum Count and the answer should be 20th = 4 and 18th = 3. So in comparison we have increased by 1 ID_NUMBER on the 20th

Date sample

```
REPORT_DATE | ID_NUMBER    
20-03-19    | GRS333
20-03-19    | GRS386
20-03-19    | GRS367
20-03-19    | GRS311
18-03-19    | GRS313
18-03-19    | GRS313
18-03-19    | GRS313
11-01-19    | GRS367
```

Comment: Please add your expected output to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try aggregating and then using `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT REPORT_DATE, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY REPORT_DATE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

### Demo

Comment: This would work however with the < sign added will this not also add in the data anything less than MAX so this will include the 11th's data too but im only after the 18th's in this date but i cannot hard code the date as trying to make it dynamic. Thanks

Comment: I disagree with your comment, and I think both of my queries should be working.  Check the demo link I added to the answer.

Comment: I have ran your query and agree how its working now, is there anyway i can do a distinct count of the ID_NUMBER columns to return a single value ? i tried SELECT Count (DISTINCT ID_NUMBER), REPORT_DATE but getting error....:(